# Filter elements out of a jquery object based on text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, dom-manipulation

I am trying to use `contains` with 'this' keyword, but it is giving an error.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var check=$('ul').find('li').filter(function(){
        return $(this:contains('two')).css('color','red')
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li id="one">one</li>
    <li id="two">two</li>
    <li id="one">one</li>
    <li id="two">two</li>
    <li id="one">one</li>
    <li id="two">two</li>
    <li id="one">one</li>
    <li id="two">two</li>
    <li id="one">one</li>
    <li id="two">two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you want to make sure that "two" exists within it? or that "two" is the only thing within it?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the close parenthesis: `$(this).contains(...`

Comment: `var check = $("ul li:contains('two')").css('color', 'red');`

Comment: Your syntax looks bad and your use of `contains` uninformed.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique on the page. Your code may just be for demonstration purposes but you need to be aware of this limitation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pH4m8/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('ul').find('li').filter(function () {
        return this.innerHTML == 'two';
    }).css('color','red')
})
```

---

Or to match it anywhere in the element (rather than only "two" being within it):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pH4m8/2/)

```
$(function () {
    $('ul').find('li').filter(function () {
        return /two/.test(this.innerHTML);
    }).css('color','red')
})
```

---

Also, if it matters... chaining methods (`.find().filter()`) seems to be faster than using `contains`:

[Performance test created for this specifically](http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-contains-sm)
[Another related test](http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-contains)

And your id's should be unique - but I'm assuming that it is just copy/pasting for sample code and that you don't actually have duplicate id's in your actual code.

Answer (score 8):

Without `filter` as simple as

```
$("ul li:contains('two')").css('color', 'red');
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1494/)

Comment: this could be as well an accepted answer!

Comment: This is case-sensitive variant. Use should use`toLowerCase()` for icontains.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).text() == 'two';
```

Get the current li's text & check if it has the value "two".

Comment: I see what you're saying