# Programmatically set the text of a select - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to programmatically set an option of an existing select box when I only know the text of the option and not the value.

Here is my code:

```
$("#" + eventQuestions[x].code).find('option[text="' + eventAnswers[x].vAnswerString + '"]').attr("selected");
```

Don't focus too much on selecting the right html element or the right text being inside the vAnswerString - I can confirm those are correct.

Basically the option is not being selected. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: is `text` an actual attribute value of the option, i.e., `<option text=something value=somethingElse>` or is it `<option value=something>some text</option>` because if it is the second case, your selector will not work

Comment: the attr function returns the current value of the attribute when not providing a second parameter.

To add the selected attribute do $(**).attr("selected" , true)

Comment: Check here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317082/filter-elements-out-of-a-jquery-object-based-on-text-content

Comment: add a filter to your selector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/496052/771578

Comment: @chiliNUT It is the second case. Thanks for pointing that out. I will need to find how to select the option when I only know `<option>this text</option>`

Comment: @btf NP. check out tellez's link, it references the jquery-only pseudo-selector `:contains` which is exactly what you need for this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317082/filter-elements-out-of-a-jquery-object-based-on-text-content) answer.

You can use that filter to check the inner text and then you put the selected attribute like this:

```
.attr("selected", true);
```

Example I tested it with:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select").find("option").filter(function() {
        return this.innerHTML == "InnerText";
    }).attr("selected", true);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/yatpaccs/) for jquery 1.6+.

Select the option using the filter function:

```
var text = "theTextToFind";
var matchingOption = $("select#myselect option").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == text;
    });
```

Set the value using the property function:

```
matchingOption.prop('selected', true);
```

Also check out this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496126/4347337).